# Как решить проблему с позиционированием?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, вёрстка, позиционирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите, Я делаю подобие игрового инвентаря. Когда я вставляю предмет в инвентарь,то он встает казалось бы нормально. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я делаю прокрутку инвентаря,то предмет движется вместе со скроллом

```
.inv-content { // стили контейнера,в котором находятся ячейки
    width:474px;
    height:1050px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:flex-start;
    flex-wrap:wrap; 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
}

content.addEventListener('drop', (event)=>{ 
    currentThing.style.position = 'absolute';
    item = event.target;
    let rect = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(item.offsetTop)

    currentThing.style.top = item.offsetTop + 'px';
    currentThing.style.left = item.offsetLeft + 'px';
    currentThing.style.zIndex = 1000;
    currentThing.style.margin = '0';

    content.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',currentThing);
});
```

в js я назначаю предмету pos:absolute и вставляю его в контейнер, где он должен позиционироваться относительно контейнера.

Если нужно еще информация то пишите, все скину!!!

Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: нужен полный код

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1inEVVQaSguqRl5OOw4PJmvLKd-DzOzax

Answer (score 0):

**js**

```
content.addEventListener('drop', event => {
  currentThing.style.position = 'absolute';
  item = event.target;

  currentThing.style.top = item.offsetTop + 'px';
  currentThing.style.left = item.offsetLeft + 'px';
  currentThing.style.zIndex = 1000;
  currentThing.style.margin = '0';
  event.currentTarget.append(currentThing); // поменял
});
```

**css**(внутри `@media (min-width:1220px) and (max-width:1649px)`)

```
.inv-content {
  width: 354px;
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative; // добавил
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю,что вы за человек,но я бы пожал вам руку. Скажу вам честно, вы спасли мою жизнь.